# How can I convert CSV files with a meta data header row into flat tables using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a few thousand CSV files with a format similar to this (i.e. a table with a meta data row at the top):

```
dinosaur.csv,water,Benjamin.Field.12.Location53.Readings,
DATE,VALUE,QUALITY,STATE
2018-06-01,73.83,Good,0
2018-06-02,45.53,Good,0
2018-06-03,89.123,Good,0
```

Is it possible to use PowerShell to convert these CSV files into a simple table format such as this?

```
DATE,VALUE,QUALITY,STATE,FILENAME,PRODUCT,TAG
2018-06-01,73.83,Good,0,dinosaur.csv,water,Benjamin.Field.12.Location53.Readings
2018-06-02,45.53,Good,0,dinosaur.csv,water,Benjamin.Field.12.Location53.Readings
2018-06-03,89.123,Good,0,dinosaur.csv,water,Benjamin.Field.12.Location53.Readings
```

Or is there a better alternative to preparing these CSV's into a straight forward format to be ingested?

I have used PS to process simple CSV's before, but not with a meta data row that was important.

Thanks

Comment: This would be easy if the metadata row is structured the same across your 'few thousand' of CSV files.  The question becomes, is that metadata row always in the same place, always structured the same, and always split into the same columns you've provided in the second representation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This is a *faster alternative* to [thepip3r's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59904193/45375), and also covers the aspect of saving the modified content back to CSV files:

By using the [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) statement to efficiently loop over the lines of the files as *text*, the costly calls to  `ConvertFrom-Csv`, `Select-Object` and `Export-Csv` can be avoided.

Note that the `switch` statement is enclosed in `$()`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), so as to enable writing back to the same file in a single pipeline; however, doing so requires keeping the entire (modified) file in memory; if that's not an option, enclose the `switch` statement in `& { ... }` and pipe it to `Set-Content` to a *temporary* file, which you can later use to replace the original file.

```
# Create a sample CSV file in the current dir.
@'
dinosaur.csv,water,Benjamin.Field.12.Location53.Readings,
DATE,VALUE,QUALITY,STATE
2018-06-01,73.83,Good,0
2018-06-02,45.53,Good,0
2018-06-03,89.123,Good,0
'@ > sample.csv

# Loop over all *.csv files in the current dir.
foreach ($csvFile in Get-Item *.csv) {

  $ndx = 0
  $(
    switch -File $csvFile.FullName {
      default {
        if ($ndx -eq 0) {  # 1st line
          $suffix = $_ -replace ',$' # save the suffix to append to data rows later
        } elseif ($ndx -eq 1) {  # header row
          $_ + ',FILENAME,PRODUCT,TAG' # add additional column headers
        } else { # data rows
          $_ + ',' + $suffix  # append suffix
        }
        ++$ndx
      }
    }
  ) # | Set-Content $csvFile.FullName  # <- activate this to write back to the same file.
    # Use -Encoding as needed.

}
```

The above yields the following:

```
DATE,VALUE,QUALITY,STATE,FILENAME,PRODUCT,TAG
2018-06-01,73.83,Good,0,dinosaur.csv,water,Benjamin.Field.12.Location53.Readings
2018-06-02,45.53,Good,0,dinosaur.csv,water,Benjamin.Field.12.Location53.Readings
2018-06-03,89.123,Good,0,dinosaur.csv,water,Benjamin.Field.12.Location53.Readings
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ## If your inital block is an accurate representation
$s = get-content .\test.txt

## Get the 'metadata' line
$metaline = $s[0]

## Remove the metadata line from the original and turn it into a custom powershell object
$n = $s | where-object { $_ -ne $metaline } | ConvertFrom-Csv

## Split the metadata line by a comma to get the different parts for appending to the other content
$m = $metaline.Split(',')

## Loop through each item  and append the metadata information to each entry
for ($i=0; $i -lt $n.Count; $i++) {
    $n[$i] = $n[$i] | Select-Object -Property *,FILENAME,PRODUCT,TAG  ## This is a cheap way to create new properties on an object
    $n[$i].Filename = $m[0]
    $n[$i].Product  = $m[1]
    $n[$i].Tag      = $m[2]
}

## Display that the new objects reports as the desired output
$n | format-table
```